# Why don't O3 less than O1 in gpu memory?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, apex

i'm training EfficientDet-D7(head_only=True) in 2080TI * 1.

And i'm using NVIDIA/APEX:amp.

When i use `opt_level=O1`, although the memory is definitely reduced compared to when apex is not used.

But, when I use `opt_level=O2`or`O3`, more memory is consumed.

I am experimenting with the same `2080 Ti`, each with a separate GPU by creating two containers with the same docker image. The learning code also copied the code using `O1` as it is and changed it to `O3`, and the `args` required for learning are all the same. (The batch size and `d7` are also the same.)

Why happen this... TT

Additionally, Can you recommend the book about this?(ex. deep learning Memory, gpu ... etc)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know here, but in general, optimisation levels O2 and O3 are for more *speed*, not for less *memory*.

Comment: When I use `O1`, 9596 memory is used, but when I use `O3`, OOM occurs in same batch size.

Comment: Thanks!  @9769953
I agree with you, but I was expecting more memory savings in general though.

Comment: @YeonsikChoi Why do you expect memory savings when optimizing for speed?

Comment: @YeonsikChoi it would be helpful if you can provide details about your environment (Versions of Python, CUDA, Pytorch, etc.) and a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi @klutt !

Becuz, when I use `O1`, i could save my memory than `O0`.
And i think `opt_level = O3` use `dtype=float16` more than `O1`.

Thanks.

Comment: @YeonsikChoi The memory savings are just a byproduct of speed optimization.

Comment: Hi @DivyeshPeshavaria

[In Docker]
torch=1.9.0
cuda=10.2
cudnn=7
Python=3.7.10

[Code]
https://github.com/zylo117/Yet-Another-EfficientDet-Pytorch
- train.py

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're optimizing for speed. Some speed optimizations will reduce memory usage. Other will increase them.

- An example of when speed optimization reduces memory usage is when unnecessary variables and function calls are removed.
- An example of the opposite is loop unrolling.

There's no reason to expect optimization to either reduce or increase memory usage. That's not the goal when optimizing for speed. Any increase or decrease is just a byproduct.

If you really want to find out why it happens in your particular case, you can study the documentation for your compiler and inspect the assembly code.